# Git - removing objects/large .git directory

Tags: git

I am new to git. I had an existing codebase with a couple of hundred php files and a directory with many thousands of uploaded files&images in uploads/.

When I created my git repo, and pushed my codebase to the remote server, I mistakenly forgot to put the uploads/ directory into .gitignore and have been running into trouble since :(

Firstly, I have since added that directory to my .gitignore

Second, I have removed that directory from tracking by running "git rm --cached filename" for all files in the uploads/ directory.

However, it seems all those images are still being stored by git, as my .git folder is over 1GB and whenever I clone my repo it counts tens of thousands of "objects" -- I beleive this in only possible if its including the uploads/ directory.

I have tried the following (from http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html) to no avail:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Any solutions short of un-giting my codebase and starting from scratch!?

Thanks!

Comment: If those objects are in your history at all, they will take up space.  You may have to rewrite the history of the entire git repo to remove those objects.  You can do that with `git filter-branch` probably.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, garbage collecting is not enough and you will have to modify the history. 
Look at [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which make it easier, but not without risk nor consequences. That's better you read a little about that (there is also already some answers about that).